# MongooseArray#indexOf not working with object ids

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to use mongoose's built in indexOf() method to see if an object id exists in a doc array. But it does not appear to work with object ids, even though the documentation says it should.

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
  , following : [{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}]
  , followers : [{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}]
});
```

This is giving me -1

```
user1.followers.indexOf(user2._id);
```

For the following data:

```
console.log( user1.followers ) # => [ '505e2f1de888c7d701000001' ]
conosle.log( user2._id ) # => 505e2f1de888c7d701000001
console.log( user1.followers.indexOf( user2._id ) ) # => -1
```

I have also tried passing just user2 object, but same problem:

```
console.log( user1.followers.indexOf( user2 ) ) # => -1
```

I should be seeing 1 in the last log here, not -1.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the mongoose documentation:
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#types_array_MongooseArray-indexOf

Comment: The parameter has to be object. `user1.followers.indexOf(user2);`

Comment: still does not work. -- isFollowing
[ '50680445639190c06a000002', '505e2f1de888c7d701000001' ]
505e2f1de888c7d701000001
-1

Comment: I don't think the doc for MongooseArray exists anymore. Now it's pretty difficult to know if `indexOf` should work by passing in an `ObjectId` b.c. of strict comparison

Answer (score 4):

Old question, but this bit me recently so I'll post my solution for others burning the midnight oil:

```
user1.followers.indexOf(user2._id.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I was using the user stored in session, not user object from db. Also, it infact does have to be an object id that is passed:

```
User.findById(req.session.userid, function(err, user){
  user2.isFollowing = user.following.indexOf(user2._id);
});
```

Storing objects in session is bad. Should always retrieve them from db so they don't get stale and you have a true mongoose doc object, not a json object from redis store.